# run few commands simultaneously

Tags: shell

I am writting a shell script and i want these commands to run at the same time

```
find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 1' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 1 | next_command >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1
find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 2' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 2 | next_command >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1
find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 0' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 3 | next_command  >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1
```

is it possible to use & to let all of them to run at the same time? if it is possible, can I run the following command to output the log only after all three of the above commands finished execution?

```
tail log/foo_log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough, you can use `wait` to pause until all the processes have exited.

> `wait: wait [n]`
>       Wait for the specified process and report its termination status.  If
>       N is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for,
>       and the return code is zero.  N may be a process ID or a job
>       specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in the job's
>       pipeline are waited for.

Voilà!

```
find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 1' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 1 | next_command >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1 &
find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 2' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 2 | next_command >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1 &
find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 0' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 3 | next_command  >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1 &
wait
tail log/foo_log
```

Answer (score 0):

i saw [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/48276-bash-can-i-run-background-pipes.html) discussion while searching for solution, so i thought I would try answering my own question XD

```
(find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 1' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 1 | next_command >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1) &
(find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 2' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 2 | next_command >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1) &
(find ./incoming/kontraktor/ -type f -name '*.html' | sort | awk 'NR % 3 == 0' | ./bin/foo.py -m 3 -b 3 | next_command  >> log/foo_log.log 2>&1) &
wait
```